# How to force another parallel component to refresh in react

Tags: reactjs

I have splitted my page into few components and I need to force the other components to refresh their contents on the screen whenever a change happens in one of them.

It is possible to force parent and child components in react js to refresh each other but I wonder how I can handle this scenario when the components are not parent and child .

I know one way is to merge all of them in a single component and handle that but it makes source un-modular.

I have googled this and all the posts are about parent and child components.

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: this sounds like a great use case for `Redux`. You can update a store value, and each child subscribes to that store and change accordingly

Comment: @JohnRuddell , isn't there any other way to do it by Reactjs except using Redux?

Comment: React has a context api. Have you read about that yet? you can make providers / consumers for a piece of data. each component could listen to that context. [Helpful article explaining how to do it](https://itnext.io/understanding-the-react-context-api-through-building-a-shared-snackbar-for-in-app-notifications-6c199446b80c)

Comment: @JohnRuddell, I appreciate that

Comment: You don't need redux nor React context, you have to manage the state on the common parent, then pass down the properties, read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: @ramirozap the OP said `how I can handle this scenario when the components are not parent and child`. If you dont have a parent child relationship how would you do it? :)

Comment: @ramirozap, Thanks for your answer, does updating the parent's state in one child cause the other child to show the changes on its part automatically?

Comment: @JohnRuddell, I can have all these parallel childs under one parent

Comment: @albertsh if they all have the same parent then you could use parent state, pass that state to all of the children. They will re-render if that state variable changes.

Comment: @JohnRuddell, Oh I thought only the current child and its parent will rerender the page, Thanks for your comments

Comment: if you'd like to post a fiddle with an example of the parent / child relationship I can help you get to where you want to be :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194266/discussion-between-albert-sh-and-john-ruddell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use some form of state management solution, be it [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
This is the only scalable solution to updating multiple components that are not directly hierarchical.